# Using Third party apis in firefoxaddonsdk

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to use ericvold's toolbar button module in my extension. When I try it online using the Add-on Builder it works fine. But when I do it using the Add-on SDK on my computer it seems to have some issues and nothing seems to be added any where.

The steps that I have followed are:

- Download the toolbar as a zip from [github](https://github.com/erikvold/toolbarbutton-jplib).
- Uncompress it and add it to my packages in the Add-on SDK and run `cfx docs`.
- Copy the documentation listed in the `index.html` (Third party apis) into the `main.js`.
- Add the dependency in my `packages.json` (vold utils was also downloaded and added).

It still does not show me a toolbar.

My code is this:

```
exports.main = function(options) {
  // create toolbarbutton
  var tbb = require("toolbarbutton").ToolbarButton({
    id: "TBB-TEST",
    label: "TBB TEST",
    onCommand: function () {
      tbb.destroy();
    }
  });

  if (options.loadReason == "install") {
    tbb.moveTo({
      toolbarID: "nav-bar",
      forceMove: false // only move from palette
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: So, in which directory do you have your `main.js` and where is `toolbarbutton.js`?

Comment: main.js is in the lib directory and toolbarbutton.js is in the packages directory- D:\addon-sdk-1.6.1\packages\erikvold-toolbarbutton-jplib-46e51ab\lib\toolbarbutton.js

Comment: NOne whatsoever in my command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a github repo you can look at:

https://github.com/canuckistani/toolbar-template

This is basic add-on that has git submodules pointing to Erik Vold's toobar and utils libraries, and implements a very simple toolbar button.

```
const data = require("self").data;
const tabs = require("tabs");

exports.main = function(options) {

    var btn = require("toolbarbutton").ToolbarButton({
        id: 'my-toolbar-button',
        label: 'Add skull!',
        image: data.url('favicon.png'),
        onCommand: function() {
            if (typeof(tabs.activeTab._worker) == 'undefined') {
                let worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
                    contentScript: 'self.port.on("sayhello", function() { alert("Hello world!"); })'
                });
                tabs.activeTab._worker = worker;
            }
            tabs.activeTab._worker.port.emit("sayhello");
        }
    });

    if (options.loadReason === "install") {
        btn.moveTo({
          toolbarID: "nav-bar",
          forceMove: false // only move from palette
        });
  }
};
```

To see how it works, simple install the xpi file:

https://github.com/canuckistani/toolbar-template/raw/master/toolbar.xpi

Note: this example works with SDK verison 1.7, it wil probably not work qwith the SDK master branch due to changes in exports.main().

Answer (score 1):

Change `D:\addon-sdk-1.6.1\packages\erikvold-toolbarbutton-jplib-46e51ab\lib\toolbarbutton.js` to `D:\addon-sdk-1.6.1\packages\toolbarbutton\lib\toolbarbutton.js`

Comment: same thing for the `vold-utils` package too

Comment: That didnt work. But your menuitem module seems to work fine. I can see the click me in the tools.

Comment: Okay. I guess it was my bad. I had to go to firefox tab, toolbar layout and then select the toolbar. How do i make it appear automatically.